# Contact Form 7 Css Styling

Tags: wordpress, css, stylesheet

I've recently got a premium theme, and the form for mailchimp looks really cool.

I was wondering if I can use the style for my 3 Field Based Contact form
"REQUEST A CALL BACK" - Name Input Field, Number Input Field, and CALL ME button.

Upon Inspection via Chrome Inspector, following is used for mailchimps form field

```
.subscribe-box .form-control {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #4c5462;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 0 158px 0 50px;
}


.form-control {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 34px;
padding: 6px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
-webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
-o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
```

}

and looks like this

[SUBSCRIBE FORM FIELD WITH BUTTON ABSOLUTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCq3z.jpg)

Since I wana use contact forms. I want to have my form fields inline (single line), with a CALL BUTTON on the NUMBER FORM FIELD.

Something like this
[THAT I"D LOVE TO HAVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QV2D.jpg)
but doest have to be inline in phone view

Following is my ContactForm

```
[text* text-833 "NAME"] 
[tel* tel-572 "PHONE"] 
[submit "CALL ME"]
```

Any help/input is appreciated
Regards

Comment: for making the two input in one line you have to do css as that will not going to work as it is for only 1 input

Answer (score 0):

from what I've read you need help in applying these styles.

A way that you can do this, is to use a custom CSS editor plugin such as [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/). From there, you can apply these styles to all of your forms.

Another way of doing this is to add a class to each shortcode by using "class:your-class-name". For example:

```
[text* text-833 "NAME" class:textstyle]
```

Then once again from your custom CSS editor you can apply these styles.

Comment: nope didnt work, Actually i need inline form. As in all the fields in single line